# Undesirable watcher execution order

Tags: vuejs2

I have a dropdown component that has two props:  'val', 'options' (array of objects). The component is driven off local versions of these values 'locVal' and 'locOptions' which are updated through the two public watched props.

The parent needs to be able to provide the 'options' array and/or the 'val' at any time in any order and my watchers decide how to update the internal values so they are always in a consistent state:

```
watch: {
  val() {
    // validate 'val' against 'locOptions' and set 'locVal' if match
  },
  options() {
    // validate 'locVal' against 'options' and leave 'locVal' alone
    // if still match otherwise set to null
    // also set 'locOptions' to 'options'           
  }
},
```

There is a problem however with the order in which Vue calls the watched functions. They are not called in the order the values where changed but instead in the order of declaration.

Assume the initial internal values:

```
locOptions = [
   { val: 1, text: 'one' },
   { val: 2, text: 'two' )
];
locVal = 1;
```

```
// parent sets the props in this order
val = 3;
options = [
   { val: 3, text: 'three' },
   { val: 4, text: 'four' )
];
// desired outcome
'locVal' should be null
'val' is set to mirror 'locVal' with two way binding
```

Here the 'val' is first matched to 'locOptions'. It fails to match so to enforce validation the component sets 'locVal' and 'val' to null (the only viable value if no match). After, when the 'options' is matched against the 'locVal' it leaves 'locVal' alone since null is still a viable value for the new set.

```
// setting the props in opposite order
options = [
   { val: 3, text: 'three' },
   { val: 4, text: 'four' )
];
val = 3;
// desired outcome
'locVal' should be 3
'val' is set to mirror 'locVal' with two way binding
```

In this scenario 'options' are first matched against the 'locVal'. It fails as '1' is not in the new list so 'locVal' and 'val' are set to null. Then 'val' is matched to 'locOptions'. It matches thus 'locVal' and 'val' get set to 3.

How can I get Vue to observe the order in which these props where changed to get the desired behavior?

Comment: I don't understand why your functions don't do the same thing. They should both match `this.val` against `this.options`. In fact it should be the same function. The order they're called shouldn't matter.

Comment: I updated the entire question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Vue has (had?) an [undocumented API](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/synchronize-watch/4848/3) for watchers called `sync`.

Instead of waiting next tick to call the watchers, it calls them immediately. It's not recommended, and could lead to infinite loops if used inappropriately.

```
watch: {
  val: {
    handler () {
      // validate 'val' against 'locOptions' and set 'locVal' if match
    },
    sync: true
  }, 
  options() {
    handler() {
      // validate 'locVal' against 'options' and leave 'locVal' alone
      // if still match otherwise set to null
      // also set 'locOptions' to 'options'           
    },
    sync: true
  }
},
```